# Case Expression Issue in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am using a IF statement and using a case statement to do that. When i do so, I get an error.

Basically, if the security type = 'Currency Future.', i want to output it as 'NetDetail' else 'Detail'

The SQL statement looks like this:

The error looks like this:

```
<e>Query: SELECT `Desk`, `VT_id`, `BloombergID`,`Id_Type`,`Position` ,`Price`, `positions_desk`.`Multiplier`,`CCY`,`business_date`,`APAC_E...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE 
     WHEN (`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Security_Type`) THEN 'NetDetail'
                        ' at line 3
```

Comment: what is your condition to check?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your condition

```
SELECT `Desk`, `VT_id`, `BloombergID`,`Id_Type`,`Position` ,`Price`, `positions_desk`.`Multiplier`,`CCY`,`business_date`,`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Equity_Index`,`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Security_Type`,`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Leverage`, IF(Id_Type !='FWD',COALESCE(`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Expiry`, `CBBC_Static_Data`.`Expiration_date`), STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(`VT_id`, 7, 6),'%y%m%d') ) AS `Expiration_date`, `CBBC_Static_Data`.`Strike`
,
CASE WHEN `APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Security_Type`='YOUR Condition' THEN 'NetDetail'
                         ELSE 'Detail' 
END AS `Record_Type` FROM `risk_source`.`positions_desk`
LEFT JOIN (`risk`.`APAC_Exposures_Map`) ON`positions_desk`.`BloombergID`=UPPER(`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`BBG_Ticker`)
LEFT JOIN (`risk_source`.`CBBC_Static_Data`) ON LEFT(`positions_desk`.`BloombergID`,5) =`CBBC_Static_Data`.`CBBC_Name`
WHERE business_date= ? AND (Id_Type='FUT') AND Desk NOT IN ('HKCOI')
```

Answer (score 1):

you have missed case when statement condition
  `case when APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Security_Type`= //need  conditional value here and this selection will before table name

```
 SELECT `Desk`, `VT_id`, `BloombergID`,`Id_Type`,`Position` ,`Price`, 
`positions_desk`.`Multiplier`,`CCY`,`business_date`,
`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Equity_Index`,`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Security_Type`,
`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Leverage`,
IF(Id_Type !='FWD',COALESCE(`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Expiry`, `CBBC_Static_Data`.`Expiration_date`), 
STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(`VT_id`, 7, 6),'%y%m%d') ) AS `Expiration_date`,
`CBBC_Static_Data`.`Strike`,
(CASE WHEN (`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Security_Type`='need value') THEN 'NetDetail' ELSE 'Detail' 
END) AS `Record_Type`
    FROM `risk_source`.`positions_desk`    
    LEFT JOIN (`risk`.`APAC_Exposures_Map`) ON`positions_desk`.`BloombergID`=UPPER(`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`BBG_Ticker`)
    LEFT JOIN (`risk_source`.`CBBC_Static_Data`) ON LEFT(`positions_desk`.`BloombergID`,5) =`CBBC_Static_Data`.`CBBC_Name`
    WHERE business_date= ? AND (Id_Type='FUT') AND Desk NOT IN ('HKCOI')
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot something:

```
(CASE 
     WHEN (`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Security_Type` =  'Currency Future') THEN 'NetDetail'
                         ELSE 'Detail' 
END) AS `Record_Type`
```

The condition should be:

```
`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Security_Type` =  'Currency Future'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you test it?

```
SELECT `Desk`, `VT_id`, `BloombergID`,`Id_Type`,`Position` ,`Price`, `positions_desk`.`Multiplier`,`CCY`,`business_date`,`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Equity_Index`,`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Security_Type`,`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Leverage`, CASE WHEN(Id_Type !='FWD' THEN COALESCE(`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Expiry`, `CBBC_Static_Data`.`Expiration_date`), STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(`VT_id`, 7, 6),'%y%m%d') ) ELSE GETDATE() AS `Expiration_date`, `CBBC_Static_Data`.`Strike`
FROM `risk_source`.`positions_desk`,
(CASE 
     WHEN (`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`Security_Type`) THEN 'NetDetail'
                         ELSE 'Detail' 
END) AS `Record_Type`
LEFT JOIN (`risk`.`APAC_Exposures_Map`) ON`positions_desk`.`BloombergID`=UPPER(`APAC_Exposures_Map`.`BBG_Ticker`)
LEFT JOIN (`risk_source`.`CBBC_Static_Data`) ON LEFT(`positions_desk`.`BloombergID`,5) =`CBBC_Static_Data`.`CBBC_Name`
WHERE business_date= ? AND (Id_Type='FUT') AND Desk NOT IN ('HKCOI')
```